# An IP address widget for Qt, Similar to MFC's IP address control

Tags: qt, mfc, ip

I am looking for a widget in Qt which is similar to MFC's IP address control. Does anyone know of such a widget, or perhaps how I can create one?

Comment: sorry my english is very poor.I want to write a IP widget,like windows MFC IP widget.

Comment: I have drastically revised your question, hoping this makes things more clear. If this is incorrect, please roll it back or clarify it yourself.

Comment: thank you ,you make my question to clear

Comment: do you need support for IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 9):

I have no idea what's an MFC IP Widget, but looks like it is a Widget to enter an IP address. 
You need to use a QLineEdit with a inputMask "000.000.000.000;_"

```
QLineEdit *ipEdit = new QLineEdit();
ipEdit->setInputMask("000.000.000.000;_");
ipEdit->show();
```

Comment: In addition to this, you can set a validator (A QRegExpValidator for example) which validates the correctness of your IP.

Comment: i had realized like you say.but I want to achieve better,like MFC ip widget,it will look better.

Comment: since I don't know what you mean by MFC ip widget, can you provide an screenshoot?

Comment: @little_su If you mean you prefer 4 little QLineEdits, then why not make your own widget in the similar way as suggested, but with 4 of them, with their own masks and own validators? The basic principle is still the same.

Comment: Not good. Because it accepts 192.168.0.300 for example

Answer (score 8):

A little improvement of **jpo38**'s code...

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include "stdint.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFont>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QKeyEvent>


class IPCtrl : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IPCtrl(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~IPCtrl();

    virtual bool eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event );

public slots:
    void slotTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit );

signals:
    void signalTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit );

private:
    enum
    {
        QTUTL_IP_SIZE   = 4,// число октетов IP адресе
        MAX_DIGITS      = 3 // число символов в LineEdit
    };

    QLineEdit *(m_pLineEdit[QTUTL_IP_SIZE]);
    void MoveNextLineEdit (int i);
    void MovePrevLineEdit (int i);
};


IPCtrl::IPCtrl(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent)
{
    setFrameShape( QFrame::StyledPanel );
    setFrameShadow( QFrame::Sunken );

    QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout( this );
    setLayout( pLayout );
    pLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    pLayout->setSpacing( 0 );

    for ( int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        if ( i != 0 )
        {
            QLabel* pDot = new QLabel( ".", this );
            pDot->setStyleSheet( "background: white" );
            pLayout->addWidget( pDot );
            pLayout->setStretch( pLayout->count(), 0 );
        }

        m_pLineEdit[i] = new QLineEdit( this );
        QLineEdit* pEdit = m_pLineEdit[i];
        pEdit->installEventFilter( this );

        pLayout->addWidget( pEdit );
        pLayout->setStretch( pLayout->count(), 1 );

        pEdit->setFrame( false );
        pEdit->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );

        QFont font = pEdit->font();
        font.setStyleHint( QFont::Monospace );
        font.setFixedPitch( true );
        pEdit->setFont( font );

        QRegExp rx ( "^(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$" );
        QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, pEdit);
        pEdit->setValidator( validator );

    }

    setMaximumWidth( 30 * QTUTL_IP_SIZE );

    connect( this, SIGNAL(signalTextChanged(QLineEdit*)),
             this, SLOT(slotTextChanged(QLineEdit*)),
             Qt::QueuedConnection );
}

IPCtrl::~IPCtrl()
{

}

void IPCtrl::slotTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        if ( pEdit == m_pLineEdit[i] )
        {
            if ( ( pEdit->text().size() == MAX_DIGITS &&  pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition() ) || ( pEdit->text() == "0") )
            {
                // auto-move to next item
                if ( i+1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE )
                {
                   m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setFocus();
                   m_pLineEdit[i+1]->selectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IPCtrl::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    bool bRes = QFrame::eventFilter(obj, event);

    if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
    {
        QKeyEvent* pEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>( event );
        if ( pEvent )
        {
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
            {
                QLineEdit* pEdit = m_pLineEdit[i];
                if ( pEdit == obj )
                {
                    switch ( pEvent->key() )
                    {
                    case Qt::Key_Left:
                        if ( pEdit->cursorPosition() == 0 )
                        {
                            // user wants to move to previous item
                            MovePrevLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Right:
                        if ( pEdit->text().isEmpty() || (pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition()) )
                        {
                            // user wants to move to next item
                            MoveNextLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_0:
                        if ( pEdit->text().isEmpty() || pEdit->text() == "0" )
                        {
                            pEdit->setText("0");
                            // user wants to move to next item
                            MoveNextLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        emit signalTextChanged( pEdit );
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Backspace:
                        if ( pEdit->text().isEmpty() || pEdit->cursorPosition() == 0)
                        {
                            // user wants to move to previous item
                            MovePrevLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Comma:
                    case Qt::Key_Period:
                        MoveNextLineEdit(i);
                        break;

                    default:
                        emit signalTextChanged( pEdit );
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}

void IPCtrl::MoveNextLineEdit(int i)
{
    if ( i+1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE )
    {
        m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setFocus();
        m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setCursorPosition( 0 );
        m_pLineEdit[i+1]->selectAll();
    }
}

void IPCtrl::MovePrevLineEdit(int i)
{
    if ( i != 0 )
    {
        m_pLineEdit[i-1]->setFocus();
        m_pLineEdit[i-1]->setCursorPosition( m_pLineEdit[i-1]->text().size() );
        //m_pLineEdit[i-1]->selectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I set the position of the `IPCtrl myIPCtrl` object..??

Comment: The like and functionality is good - but how do I "    registerField("ipAddress*", ipAddressIpCtrl)"? When I do this I can never get my continue to work. or does that only work with lineedit?

Comment: the only thing i can think of is to make the four edit fields public and register those... surely there is a smarter way

Comment: The only thing missing from this class is a getter method to retrieve the value... Extracting the str is left to the reader... but the tought part has been taking care of. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I agree with little_su: QLineEdit with input mask does not look and behaves as nice as the standard Windows IP control. I worked out a complete QWidget-based IP control embedding 4 QLineEdit and 3 QLabel (for dots). It just looks and behaves perfectly as MFC/Windows IP controls.

Here is the code:

```
class IPCtrl : public QFrame
{
    typedef QFrame baseClass;

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IPCtrl(QWidget *parent);
    ~IPCtrl();

#define QTUTL_IP_SIZE 4

    virtual bool eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event );

public slots:
    void slotTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit );

signals:
    void signalTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit );

private:
    QLineEdit *(m_pLineEdit[QTUTL_IP_SIZE]);

    static std::string getIPItemStr( unsigned char item );   
};

class IPItemValidator : public QIntValidator 
{
public:
    IPItemValidator( QObject* parent ) : QIntValidator( parent )
    {
        setRange( 0, UCHAR_MAX );
    }
    ~IPItemValidator() {}

    virtual void fixup( QString & input ) const
    {
        if ( input.isEmpty() )
            input = "0";
    }
};

IPCtrl::IPCtrl(QWidget *parent) : baseClass(parent)
{
    setFrameShape( QFrame::StyledPanel );
    setFrameShadow( QFrame::Sunken );

    QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout( this );
    setLayout( pLayout );
    pLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    pLayout->setSpacing( 0 );

    for ( int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        if ( i != 0 )
        {
            QLabel* pDot = new QLabel( ".", this );
            pDot->setStyleSheet( "background: white" );
            pLayout->addWidget( pDot );
            pLayout->setStretch( pLayout->count(), 0 );
        }

        m_pLineEdit[i] = new QLineEdit( this );
        QLineEdit* pEdit = m_pLineEdit[i];
        pEdit->installEventFilter( this );

        pLayout->addWidget( pEdit );
        pLayout->setStretch( pLayout->count(), 1 );

        pEdit->setFrame( false );
        pEdit->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );

        QFont font = pEdit->font();
        font.setStyleHint( QFont::Monospace );
        font.setFixedPitch( true );
        pEdit->setFont( font );

        pEdit->setValidator( new IPItemValidator( pEdit ) );
    }

    setMaximumWidth( 30 * QTUTL_IP_SIZE );

    connect( this, SIGNAL(signalTextChanged(QLineEdit*)),
             this, SLOT(slotTextChanged(QLineEdit*)),
             Qt::QueuedConnection );
}

IPCtrl::~IPCtrl()
{

}

std::string IPCtrl::getIPItemStr( unsigned char item )
{
    std::strstream str;
    str << (int) item;
    str << std::ends;
    return str.str();
}

void IPCtrl::slotTextChanged( QLineEdit* pEdit )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        if ( pEdit == m_pLineEdit[i] )
        {
            if ( pEdit->text().size() == getIPItemStr( UCHAR_MAX ).size() &&
                 pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition() )
            {
                // auto-move to next item
                if ( i+1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE )
                {
                   m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setFocus();
                   m_pLineEdit[i+1]->selectAll();
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IPCtrl::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    bool bRes = baseClass::eventFilter(obj, event);

    if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
    {
        QKeyEvent* pEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>( event );
        if ( pEvent )
        {
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i )
            {
                QLineEdit* pEdit = m_pLineEdit[i];
                if ( pEdit == obj )
                {
                    switch ( pEvent->key() )
                    {
                    case Qt::Key_Left:
                        {
                            if ( pEdit->cursorPosition() == 0 )
                            {
                                // user wants to move to previous item
                                if ( i != 0 )
                                {
                                    m_pLineEdit[i-1]->setFocus();
                                    m_pLineEdit[i-1]->setCursorPosition( m_pLineEdit[i-1]->text().size() );
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case Qt::Key_Right:
                        {
                            if ( pEdit->text().isEmpty() ||
                                 (pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition()) )
                            {
                                // user wants to move to next item
                                if ( i+1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE )
                                {
                                    m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setFocus();
                                    m_pLineEdit[i+1]->setCursorPosition( 0 );
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            emit signalTextChanged( pEdit );
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

Comment: does it support IPv6 addresses?

Comment: How can I set the position of the `IPCtrl  myIPCtrl` object..??

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement of Tugo's code... I cannot comment so...

- classic array to std::array
- setter and getter
- remove styleSheet, u can use your own

ipctrl.h :

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <QFrame>
#include <array>

/// Thanx to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11358560/8524139
class QLineEdit;
class IPCtrl : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
    enum
    {
        QTUTL_IP_SIZE = 4, // число октетов IP адресе
        MAX_DIGITS = 3     // число символов в LineEdit
    };

public:
    IPCtrl(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~IPCtrl();

    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

    std::array<quint8, QTUTL_IP_SIZE> getIP() const;
    void setIP(std::array<quint8, QTUTL_IP_SIZE> ipAddr);

signals:
    void signalTextChanged(QLineEdit *pEdit);

private:
    std::array<QLineEdit *, QTUTL_IP_SIZE> m_pLineEdit;
    void slotTextChanged(QLineEdit *pEdit);
    void moveNextLineEdit(int i);
    void movePrevLineEdit(int i);
};
```

ipctrl.cpp :

```cpp
#include "ipctrl.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
IPCtrl::IPCtrl(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent)
{
    setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);

    QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(pLayout);
    pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 1, 0);
    pLayout->setSpacing(0);

    for (int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            QLabel *pDot = new QLabel(".", this);
            pLayout->addWidget(pDot);
            pLayout->setStretch(pLayout->count(), 0);
        }

        m_pLineEdit.at(i) = new QLineEdit(this);
        QLineEdit *pEdit = m_pLineEdit.at(i);
        pEdit->installEventFilter(this);

        pLayout->addWidget(pEdit);
        pLayout->setStretch(pLayout->count(), 1);

        pEdit->setFrame(false);
        pEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        QFont font = pEdit->font();
        font.setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace);
        font.setFixedPitch(true);
        pEdit->setFont(font);

        QRegExp rx("^(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$");
        QValidator *validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, pEdit);
        pEdit->setValidator(validator);
    }

    setMaximumWidth(30 * QTUTL_IP_SIZE);

    connect(this, &IPCtrl::signalTextChanged, this, &IPCtrl::slotTextChanged, Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

IPCtrl::~IPCtrl()
{
}

void IPCtrl::slotTextChanged(QLineEdit *pEdit)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (pEdit == m_pLineEdit.at(i))
        {
            if ((pEdit->text().size() == MAX_DIGITS && pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition())
                || (pEdit->text() == "0"))
            {
                // auto-move to next item
                if (i + 1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE)
                {
                    m_pLineEdit.at(i + 1)->setFocus();
                    m_pLineEdit.at(i + 1)->selectAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool IPCtrl::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    bool bRes = QFrame::eventFilter(obj, event);

    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *pEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if (pEvent)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i)
            {
                QLineEdit *pEdit = m_pLineEdit[i];
                if (pEdit == obj)
                {
                    switch (pEvent->key())
                    {
                    case Qt::Key_Left:
                        if (pEdit->cursorPosition() == 0)
                        {
                            // user wants to move to previous item
                            movePrevLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Right:
                        if (pEdit->text().isEmpty() || (pEdit->text().size() == pEdit->cursorPosition()))
                        {
                            // user wants to move to next item
                            moveNextLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_0:
                        if (pEdit->text().isEmpty() || pEdit->text() == "0")
                        {
                            pEdit->setText("0");
                            // user wants to move to next item
                            moveNextLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        emit signalTextChanged(pEdit);
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Backspace:
                        if (pEdit->text().isEmpty() || pEdit->cursorPosition() == 0)
                        {
                            // user wants to move to previous item
                            movePrevLineEdit(i);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Qt::Key_Comma:
                    case Qt::Key_Period:
                        moveNextLineEdit(i);
                        break;

                    default:
                        emit signalTextChanged(pEdit);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}

std::array<quint8, IPCtrl::QTUTL_IP_SIZE> IPCtrl::getIP() const
{
    std::array<quint8, QTUTL_IP_SIZE> ipAddr;
    std::transform(m_pLineEdit.cbegin(), m_pLineEdit.cend(), ipAddr.begin(),
        [](const QLineEdit *lineEdit) -> quint8 { return lineEdit->text().toUInt(); });
    return ipAddr;
}

void IPCtrl::setIP(std::array<quint8, IPCtrl::QTUTL_IP_SIZE> ipAddr)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i != QTUTL_IP_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        m_pLineEdit.at(i)->setText(QString::number(ipAddr.at(i)));
    }
}

void IPCtrl::moveNextLineEdit(int i)
{
    if (i + 1 != QTUTL_IP_SIZE)
    {
        m_pLineEdit.at(i + 1)->setFocus();
        m_pLineEdit.at(i + 1)->setCursorPosition(0);
        m_pLineEdit.at(i + 1)->selectAll();
    }
}

void IPCtrl::movePrevLineEdit(int i)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        m_pLineEdit.at(i - 1)->setFocus();
        m_pLineEdit.at(i - 1)->setCursorPosition(m_pLineEdit[i - 1]->text().size());
        // m_pLineEdit[i-1]->selectAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All `QFrame` based solutions are great but they force you to declare your own class. `QLineEdit` with input mask does not prevent '999.999.999.999' to be entered, so this is not acceptable.

Here is an easy to implement and well workign implementation using QLineEdit validator:

```
QString ipRange = "(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
QRegularExpression ipRegex("^" + ipRange + "\\." + ipRange + "\\." + ipRange + "\\." + ipRange + "$")
QRegularExpressionValidator* ipValidator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(ipRegex, NULL);
QLineEdit *ipEdit = new QLineEdit();
ipEdit->setValidator(ipValidator);
```

Note that "192.168.1" will be accepted, to you may in the end check that splitting the result with "." ends up with 4 non empty strings. Then your IP adress should be valid.