# KeyPress not firing on Android tablet

Tags: qt

I am trying to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11358560/2515293) solution for Android tablet

The problem is `QEvent::KeyPress` is not fired on a tablet when using a virtual keyboard.

After some trial and error, I found what `QEvent::InputMethod` fired instead.

So, a simple modification make it working on tablet:

```
if ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress || event->type() == QEvent::InputMethod)
```

But this is complete nonsense because one line further it is converted to `QKeyEvent`:

```
QKeyEvent* pEvent = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>( event );
```

I don't get why I don't have runtime exception, because `InputMethod` simply have no member `key()`

Even if it is working it is not safe.

How i should handle input in the correct way?

Comment: If there was a key() method wouldn't even matter, as it's a separate type. The dynamic_cast should return a null pointer though in case of an QInputMethodEvent, does it not?

Comment: No. The code is working fine with this only change.

Comment: But ok. this is not my question: It is clear what it is the wrong approach. How to handle "KeyPressed" on tablet from a virtual keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my first comment: "No. The code is working fine with this only change.". Indeed dynamic_cast return null pointer. Code is working if I make explicit conversion:  "QKeyEvent* keyEvent = (QKeyEvent*)event;". But again, it is not making any difference for my problem. It is still very wrong.