# Show QWidget as focused

Tags: c++, qt, focus, qpainter, qlineedit

I've got four `QLineEdit` placed inside of a `QLineEdit`s, where I want the first the parent to look as if it is in focus when any of the containing ones is selected. Note: I don't want the focus to actually change, just the "focus frame" (the thin blue border) to appear on the parent LineEdit.

I've tried to draw a rect, but while it works on Windows I'm running into issues of the drawn rectangle not looking like a proper rectangle on ex. Linux, where it is supposed to be rounded. Is there a way to fix this OR, if possible, just make it draw itself as focused despite focus not being on it?

Here's my attempt at drawing a custom rect, but haven't been able to make it successfully mirror the OS style properly.

```
            if (childHasFocus) {
            QPainter painter(this);

            QLineEdit textBox;
            QColor color = textBox.palette().color(QPalette::Highlight);

            painter.setPen(color);
            QRect rect;
            rect.setTopLeft(QPoint(0,0));
            rect.setWidth(this->width() - 1);
            rect.setHeight(this->height() - 1);
            painter.drawRect(rect);
        }
```

EDIT: Added an image of the desired look. Note that I'm trying to get it to look like other LineEdits focusframe independent of OS, so hardcoding a blue rectangle won't work due to ex. Linux having a rounded focusframe.

[Desired look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5C9N.png)

Comment: Use QStylePainter, and drawControl() with the control element being QStyle::CE_FocusFrame.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want such a strange behavior of the widgets? This will be very confusing for the user. This actually sounds as a perfect example of XY problem.

Comment: @Waqar Using QStyleOptionFocusRect and option.initFrom(this) together with CE_FocusFrame gives a thick black border that doesn't seem anywhere near the FocusFrame. Maybe I'm just doing something very wrong?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I've got a custom IPAddress widget that looks like a LineEdit, but consists out of 4 of them (one for each octet). For the user it'll just look like any LineEdit and I would like the focus to look like that, even if their actual focus would be inside one of four smaller LineEdits.

Comment: @Bopet So how will the user know which one of those four actually has the focus?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager The smaller ones won't be visible. As far as the user is aware, it's just one LineEdit with an inputmask.

Comment: @Bopet How about not trying to reinvent wheel and use input mask with IP address mask. See the examples here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop

Comment: There's a lot of missing functionality from just using an input mask. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306335/an-ip-address-widget-for-qt-similar-to-mfcs-ip-address-control], which uses a similar approach to mine but without any focus-frame functionality. @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it. Its a very basic class that draws the focus frame if any of the childs have focus. On focus change, we do an update (which can probably be optimized a bit to avoid unnecessary repaints).

Screenshot:

[image]

```cpp
class IPEdit : public QWidget
{
public:
    IPEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        delete layout();
        auto l = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        setFocusProxy(&a);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
        for (auto *w : {&a, &b, &c, &d}) {
            l->addWidget(w);
            w->installEventFilter(this);
        }
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e) override
    {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::FocusIn || e->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) {
            update();
        }
        return QWidget::eventFilter(o, e);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) override
    {
        QStyleOptionFrame opt;
        opt.initFrom(this);
        opt.frameShape = QFrame::StyledPanel;
        opt.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken;

        // clear mouseOver and focus state
        // update from relevant widgets
        opt.state &= ~(QStyle::State_HasFocus | QStyle::State_MouseOver);
        const auto widgets = {&a, &b, &c, &d};
        for (const QWidget *w : widgets) {
            if (w->hasFocus()) {
                opt.state |= QStyle::State_HasFocus;
            }
        }

        opt.rect = contentsRect();
        QPainter paint(this);
        paint.setClipRegion(e->region());
        paint.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ShapedFrame, &opt, &paint, this);
    }
private:
    QLineEdit a;
    QLineEdit b;
    QLineEdit c;
    QLineEdit d;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

QlineEdit class is also a qwidget, use the setFocus method

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setFocus

Comment: This would actually set the focus, no? I don't want to actually set the focus, only for it to look like it.